# Python regroup item in dictionary

Tags: python, list, split, cut

I want to make a dictionary by splitting another dictionary items by space.

Suppose a dictionary:

> "['paris', 'paris', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'paris',
>   'paris', 'paris', 'lille', 'marseille', 'toulouse', 'marseille',
>   'lille', '**mont saint martin'**, **'mont de marsan'**, 'lyon',
>   'lyon', 'lille', 'lille', 'lyon']"

and I want to have

> ['paris', 'paris', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'paris',
>   'paris', 'paris', 'lille', 'marseille', 'toulouse', 'marseille',
>   'lille', **'mont', 'saint', 'martin'**, **'mont', 'de', 'marsan'**,
>   'lyon', 'lyon', 'lille', 'lille', 'lyon']

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
>>> li = ['paris', 'paris', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'paris', 'paris', 'paris', 'lille', 'marseille', 'toulouse', 'marseille', 'lille', 'mont saint martin', 'mont de marsan', 'lyon', 'lyon', 'lille', 'lille', 'lyon']
>>> [c for e in li for c in e.split(" ")]
```

OUTPUT:

> ['paris', 'paris', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'marseille', 'paris',
>   'paris', 'paris', 'lille', 'marseille', 'toulouse', 'marseille',
>   'lille', 'mont', 'saint', 'martin', 'mont', 'de', 'marsan', 'lyon',
>   'lyon', 'lille', 'lille', 'lyon']